# Self capacitance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, capacitance, voltage

I have two spheres of metal, each of radius $1m$, these spheres are effectively an infinite distance apart.

I now connect a $1V$ power supply between these two spheres: (and wait an infinite amount of time, for the charges to reach equilibrium.)

```
   O----------------| 1V |----------------O
Sphere 1         Power Supply          Sphere 2
```

1. What property of the metal from which the spheres are made determines the magnitude of the charge on the spheres?
2. How can the magnitude of the charge on one of the spheres be calculated?
3. If one of the spheres had its mass doubled what would be the charge on the spheres be then?

*(I am hoping to discover a new equation which will allow me to solve a more in depth problem, which I dreamt up whilst sitting on the bus)*

**EDIT**

I have now discovered what I think is the equation which I was looking for: $Q=4\pi \epsilon_0 R V$ for a single isolated sphere. I therefore (by intuition) think that the equivalent for the 2 sphere set-up is $Q=2\pi \epsilon_0 R V$

Therefore the charge I was looking for would be $Q=2\pi \epsilon_0 \times 1V \times 1m=5.56325...\times10^{-10}C$

Comment: The magnitude of the charge on either sphere just depends on the voltage and the capacitance between the spheres. And the capacitance just depends on the geometry of the setup (i.e., radii of the spheres and the distance between them). Doesn't matter what metal(s) they are made out of.

Comment: @SamuelWeir So what if the spheres are an "infinite" distance apart?

Comment: As the distance between two spheres of fixed size goes to infinity, the capacitance between them goes to zero.

Comment: @SamuelWeir Surely at some point the internal repulsion of the electrons in the negative sphere will reach equilibrium with the powers supply, even if this is no longer technically capacitance.

Comment: $Q=4\pi \epsilon_0 R V$ is correct and $2π \epsilon RV$ is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the distance between the two spheres be $d$ and let one of them have a charge of $Q$ and the other, $-Q$. The net field at a point at a distance $r$ from the centre of the positively charged sphere is the sum of fields due to both charges, and the direction of field is same for both direction, i.e. towards the negatively charged sphere. Thus the field is $\displaystyle E(r) = \dfrac {Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\dfrac 1{r^2} +\dfrac1{(d-r)^2}\right)$, and the potential difference between the two spheres is:
$$ \begin{align}V &= \int_R^{d-R}\dfrac {Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\left(\dfrac 1{r^2} +\dfrac1{(d-r)^2}\right) \\[2ex]
&=\dfrac {Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0R}\left(\dfrac {-1}{r} +\dfrac1{d-r}\right)_{R}^{d-R}\\[2ex]
&=\dfrac {2Q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0R}\left(\dfrac{d-2R}{d-R}\right)
\end{align}$$
$$\therefore Q = 2\pi\varepsilon_0RV\cdot\dfrac{d-R}{d-2R}$$
Taking the limit $d\to\infty$, we get:
$$Q=2\pi\varepsilon_0RV$$
*Please correct me if i am wrong*. Hope this helps. Cheers!

Note: A mention of thanks to @Anubhav Goel, for helping me realize my previous approach using direct expressions for potential of charged sphere wasn't that good, and for pointing out the mistake in my integral. So i have edited the answer to show another method using electric field, and corrected the integral.

Comment: How did you take out PD b/w two spheres?

Comment: I used the formula for the electric potential of a solid sphere, and took the scalar sum of the potential due to each sphere at each point.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel, i suppose that method may not be the best way here. So i have edited my answer to solve the question using electric field. Thank you for your interest! :)

Comment: $R$ is the radius of the sphere, that is $\text {1m}$. Also, ∞/∞ form does not mean limit does not exist. Also my limit evaluates correctly.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel And many apologies, my integration was wrong. I have corrected it now! Thanks again!

Comment: @AnubhavGoel Could you please tell me what is wrong with it exactly? I've added a line in the first paragraph, please check it for the validity of my expression for $E$, and then evaluate the integral. I get the answer i have written above. Please for once, show me your steps too. Either you are missing something, or i am. But this way, its not going to be clear what is going wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37063/discussion-between-freezingfire-and-anubhav-goel).